# calculate how much a customer has transacted in the last 7 days and how often, from pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

What the original df looks like:

```
df.sample(n=3)
    customer_code   subscribe_date  trx_date      trx_amount
122706  ERESMLVQ    2020-09-16        2020-02-05      500
116048  DYD9NYC2    2020-12-07        2020-06-12      430
228329  H53A46HC    2020-05-11        2020-04-17      630
```

Aggregation level: 1 row equals 1 transaction date. 
I would like to calculate how many transactions (as frequency) and how much money each customer makes in the last 7 days before his subscribe date.
df contains data as far back as 2017.

The code below:

```
df['subscribe_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['subscribe_date']).dt.date

df['trx_date']=df['trx_date'].dt.date
d = {'count':'frequency','sum':'monetary'}
diff_ = df['subscribe_date'].sub(df['trx_date']).dt.days
out = (df.assign(Before=np.select([diff_>0],["Before"],"paid_date"))
.groupby(['customer_code','Before'])['trx_amount'].agg(['count','sum'])
.rename(columns=d)).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
final_dict = {i: out.loc[:,i] for i in out.columns.levels[0]}

print(final_dict['Before'])
```

returns a silent error, because it doesn't limit the number of days to 7 days for group by to do the sum and count.

As each customer's transaction value and frequency of purchases are different, the code should return a different result for each row.

Below is the expected output

```
         frequency  monetary
cust_code                     
ERESMLVQ            30.0  1500
DYD9NYC2            50.0  4200
H53A46HC            45.0  5148.03
```

Zoom into one customer:
[image]

Comment: Could you increase the sample size so we have more than 1 transaction per costumer?

Comment: Yes I think we might need several rows for each customer to identify where the code is going off of if you need any other approach. Can you try adding as many rows as much is required to each customer to test the code?

Comment: not sure here.. should i include another customer code in the sample? I believe the code pasted above is not valid to get only the total transactions in the last 7 days before the subscribe date. Let's say the subscribe date is 2020-05-20, the total expected amount is any trx amount generated between 2020-05-13 and 2020-05-20, and frequency will be how many times this customer transacted between that period.
Each customer has different subscribe dates.